# Please add "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" to edit page of tag wiki

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-wiki

I was writing a SO tag wiki for `[jdbc]` today, with some pauses now and then. Right when I was  almost finished, I *accidently* closed the browser tab. After a minute of astonishment and complete silence I realized that I did something *really* dumb and I also realized that SO didn't display an `onbeforeunload` warning message like you would retrieve when closing a window with unsubmitted question or answer.

Can you please, *please*, add this to the tag wiki edit page as well?

I am now going to search and gather some motivation to write the JDBC tag wiki in notepad once again :(

Comment: I used Firefox.

Comment: I'd start hitting `ctr + shift + t` if I were you! It works in FF too! (If you haven't completely closed the broswer....)

Comment: Unfortunately, it has some history limit of 10 tabs... Good tip though! I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: Sorry @BalusC I'll sort this out today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just fixed this in dev, it will be deployed later today. It covers both the excerpt and body.

Answer (score 3):

This is a neat trick if you're using Chrome or Firefox (but not IE (info is not retained in IE))!

Hit `Ctr + Shift + t`. This will reopen your previously closed tab(s), and your newly entered content will still be in the edit window!

You can even use this after completely closing the Chrome browser. In FF it looks like if you completely close the browser, it won't work.

I'll try it right now... Hitting Alt-F4 without submitting (also tried it on a FAQ page)....

... phew ... it works!